# Is it possible to create multiple versions of a base yaml in a single overlay with kustomize?

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

In my szenario I have multiple Microservices that share most of the structure of a kubernetes service. Say we have a structure as the following one:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: dummy
spec:
  selector:
    app: dummy
  ports:
    - name: 8080-tcp
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
```

...and assuming I have 3 services service-a, service-b, service-c.
Can I have a kustomization that gets the shown service.yaml as input, and outputs three service definition, one per service-a to c?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create multiple kustomization files to be able to do that, and then patch it for each iteration.
If I understood correctly [this is what you want to do](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/multibases/README.md), but additionally to this, you will need to create a patch in the children kustomization files like this:

```yaml
patchesStrategicMerge:
- patch-service-a.yaml
```